# Creating a customizable water tank visualisation

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have been given an assignment to create a water tank visualisation with multiple inlets and outlets. the inlets and outlets have to be dynamic, as in there could be multiple.
I have been told to make this on react, I have no idea as to how to approach this problem.
I'm not very good with css, looked up d3.js, not quite what i'm looking for.
What technologies would i need to learn to complete this assignment?
Any help would be appreciated on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Usually assignments are not out of thin air. You should have some training material at you hand to solve the issue. If this is an assigment for some sort of school. If it is an assignment  for work, then you might not be the person to solve it.

Comment: Also you need to give more details on the task. How should the visualization look like? What does dynamic really mean. You just need to give more details.

Comment: Hey! thanks for responding, I'm interning at a place and its a work assignment. What i mean by dynamic is that, the number of inlets and outlets on the tank should be variable by code.

Comment: I'm just seeking guidance on how to even approach this.

Comment: If you didn't get clear working orders, especially as an intern, you should slap your chef in the face. (This is not a real advice).

Comment: Since this is an internship, you might tell your boss, that the working assignment is too complex for you and you need to work in a different field. They (the company) cannot except an intern to do PRO work. But maybe this is a test to see what you can do.

Comment: Even, or especially, if it is a test consider approaching it as professionally as you can. "I have most of the knowledge to generally do so", assuming that to be true of course, "but I would need some background information and maybe an introduction into the special practices usually used in this company." That would seem quite professional, even for a seasonded professional and especially so for an intern.

Comment: So I ended up making a prototype somehow, This is what it looks like https://imgur.com/a/gGuxeFb  and the source if anyone's interested, https://gitlab.com/vinayak.meti/watercontainer The css is pretty dirty though.